# Why doesn't TypeScript complain about this?

Tags: generics, es6-promise, typescript-typings, typescript2.0

There is a strange behavior with the Promise typing when compiling to ES2015.

In the following code, the first two assignments (`str` and `strA`) fail complaining that *`string | number` is not assignable to `string`* because *`number` is not assignable to `string`*, and I think that is the expected behavior. But when I use a similar assignment using promises the compiler doesn't throw an error. Is it normal or is it a bug?

```js
function strOrNumFn (): string | number {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'some string' : 9;
}

const strOrNum = strOrNumFn();

// This fails as number is not assignable to string
const str: string = strOrNum;

// This fails same reason
const strA: Array<string> = [strOrNum];

// this doesn't fail, but I think it should
const strP: Promise<string> = Promise.resolve(strOrNum);
```

You can [test the example using the TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=function%20strOrNumFn%20()%3A%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20Math.random()%20%3E%200.5%20%3F%20'some%20string'%20%3A%209%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20strOrNum%20%3D%20strOrNumFn()%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20fails%20as%20number%20is%20not%20assignable%20to%20string%0D%0Aconst%20str%3A%20string%20%3D%20strOrNum%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20This%20fails%20same%20reason%0D%0Aconst%20strA%3A%20Array%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20%5BstrOrNum%5D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20this%20doesn't%20fail%2C%20but%20I%20think%20it%20should%0D%0Aconst%20strP%3A%20Promise%3Cstring%3E%20%3D%20Promise.resolve(strOrNum)%3B%0D%0A).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When I follow your link to the playground, I see a compilation error in all there statements - including the one you say doesn't fail.

Answer (score 0):

This should be work:

```
function strOrNumFn (): string | number {
    return Math.random() > 0.5 ? 'some string' : 9;
}

const strOrNum = strOrNumFn();

// This fails as number is not assignable to string
const str: string | number  = strOrNum;

// This fails same reason
const strA: Array<string | number> = [strOrNum];

// this doesn't fail, but I think it should
const strP: Promise<string | number> = Promise.resolve(strOrNum);
```